# How to update List box with new added value of same id?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

when I add new value in List box it should be updated with new value of same id. I am unable to do it. I am trying to sum values of same id from Datagridview and want to display result in List box My code is not working.

```
    Dim results = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Decimal))()
    For i = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim laborerId As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        Dim uniqueKey As Integer = laborerId
        Dim share As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
        Dim prebal As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Label6.Text)
        Dim postbal As Integer = 0
        If Not results.ContainsKey(uniqueKey) Then results.Add(uniqueKey, New List(Of Decimal)())
        results(uniqueKey).Add(share)
        For Each key In results.Keys
            Dim sum123 = results(key).Sum()
            Dim x As String
            x = uniqueKey
            Dim p As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Do While (i >= 0)
                i = (i - 1)
                For Each dr In ListBox1.Items
                    If dr = x Then
                        ListBox1.Items.Remove(dr)
                    End If
                Next
            Loop
            ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(ces, uniqueKey, prebal, sum123, postbal))

        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Learn to use the debugger to step through code like this to see why something isn't working.  You should never delete items from a for-each loop.  `dr = x` looks suspicious because the comparison doesn't seem to match what you are adding to the list at the bottom.

Comment: You might find this a whole lot simpler if you use data bindings.  Store your data in something like a data file able the updates to that data are near automatic